# What's the canonical way to use the fmtlib with wofstream

Tags: c++, fmt, wofstream

We're switching to the fmt library and aim to rewrite many wide character output stream based formattings.

I found `fmt::output_file` which returns a `class ostream : private detail::buffer<char>` instance but it looks like there's no support for wchar_t.

What's the canonical way to use the format library in wide character output stream scenarios?

The only way i can think of is to manually open a `std::wofstream` and use `fmt::format`.
Is this on a roadmap or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fmt/ostream.h`](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ostream-api) provides an `fmt::print` overload that can write to `wofstream`:

```cpp
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::wofstream ofs("foo");
  fmt::print(ofs, L"The answer is {}.\n", 42);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YGnsTM)

That said, I would recommend avoiding `wchar_t` if you care about portability and performance.

Comment: Whoa, i didn't know gcc and clang don't accept wchar_t in wofstream's ctor